# How to hide Trusted Web Activity error toasts

Tags: android, trusted-web-activity

When migrating from Custom Tabs to Trusted Web Activity, I've noticed that whenever error happens -> whether the Digital Assets Link is not verified or Internet connection is lost, a toast with the error message pops up.

[image]

Is there any way I can stop this toasts from showing?

Answer (score 0):

A Trusted Web Activity's main feature is removing the URL bar on the top, which requires the Digital Asset Links validation. If that fails, the URL bar is not removed.

If, in your use case, you don't have a need to remove the URL bar, I'd recommend continuing to use the Custom Tabs, so you won't get the Toast.

If you need to remove the URL bar, fixing the underlying Digital Asset Links validation issues will remove both the URL bar and the Toast.

Comment: I do want to remove the URL bar this why I'm using TWA, but even when configuring the digital assets it may still fail because the chrome is caching the old assetlinks.json file.
It'd be nice to not show this error toast when verification fails for any reason

Comment: Is this an issue specific to your local device? Could you try clearing storage/data for Chrome and see if it still happens?

Comment: It worked fine after clearing Chrome cache, but we don't want other clients to see this error toast if their chrome is caching the old assetlinks file

Comment: Turns out the error toast only shows when I run the app directly from Android Studio, but when I make a build it no longer appears

Comment: Your web server shouldn't be serving the old assetlinks anymore, so your users should only get the new one.